# PHP script to copy a MySQL database including its views?

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a MySQL database on Windows Server 2008 R2 called LIVE. I have written a script to copy the LIVE database and name it REPORT. My script should check if a database called REPORT exists in MySQL and if it does then replace it with a new copy of LIVE and if not then it should create a new database called REPORT. It should then copy everything of the database including all the tables and the views. 
Here is my script:

```
    function duplicateDatabase($sourceDB=NULL, $targetDB=NULL) {

        $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES FROM ' . $sourceDB) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            mysql_query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `' . $targetDB . '`.`' . $row[0] . '`') or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query('CREATE TABLE `' . $targetDB . '`.`' . $row[0] . '` LIKE `' . $sourceDB . '`.`' . $row[0] . '`') or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query('INSERT INTO `' . $targetDB . '`.`' . $row[0] . '` SELECT * FROM `' . $sourceDB . '`.`' . $row[0] . '`') or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query('OPTIMIZE TABLE `' . $targetDB . '`.`' . $row[0] . '`') or die(mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
        mysql_close($link);
    } 
    duplicateDatabas('LIVE', 'REPORT');
```

I keep getting an error saying that it cannot copy the views in my database. Can someone please edit my script so that it does exactly what I want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHOW TABLES command will list views along the tables, however, it does not distinguish between the 2. Your script does not even attempt to handle views differently, therefore it handles them exactly as if they were tables.

1. Use [SHOW FULL TABLES FROM dbname](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html) command (or query tables and views from information_schema), which will include an extra column to enable dinstinguishing between tables (base table) and views (view).
2. Modify your php code and based on the type of the object (table or view) issue appropriate drop / create commands. For views do not do inserts and optimize commands.